# Centering element in Div tag

Tags: html, css

I have a image in div. I want set vertical align bottom and Horizontal Align center for image in div.

to center element i use align but my element  set right position.

```
  <asp:Repeater ID="product" runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>
  <div style="float: right; width: 180px; height: 177px; margin: 0 30PX 10px 5px">
     <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
        <font color="white">
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label></font>
        <br />
        <div style="height:140px ; overflow:hidden">
           <asp:Image ID="Image1"  runat="server"  Width="120px" ImageUrl='<%#  Eval("Image") %>' ImageAlign="Bottom" />
       </div>
      </asp:Panel>
 </div>
  </ItemTemplate>
```

Example :
[image]

Comment: Rendered HTML only please. I don't know ASP, and I don't intend to learn it just to understand your question.

Answer (score 6):

if img tag has not `float` assigned then simply adding `text-align : center` to `div` will solve the problem.

```
<div style="text-align:center">
    <asp:Image runat="server" ID="Image1" Width="140px" ImageUrl="" />
  </div>
```

**EDIT :**

check this demo : [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mePzB/1/)

Comment: i have edited post.check your code to be exactly same as the posted code.and make sure other styles not affecting your style.

Comment: Thanks, but i want set image bottom and center of div... i use text-align:center but don't set image.

Comment: i have provided a live demo.check it.

Comment: Thanks but when i use this code in my code don't set center :(

Comment: try setting img tag float to none explicitly(e.g: style="float:none;")

Comment: i use this " <div  style="overflow: hidden;text-align:center; height: 140px; position: relative">
                                             <asp:Image  ID="Image1"  Style="float:none; position: absolute; bottom: 0px;  display: block;" runat="server" Width="140px" ImageUrl='<%#  Eval("Image")%>' />
                                           </div>" ... but don't set :(

Comment: remove  position: relative from div and  position: absolute; bottom: 0px; from img and add my code instead.

Comment: remove display:block from img as well .

Comment: remove all the rules you already use.and use what i mentioned in the demo.it must work.

Comment: i remove all style and use this code but set image top/center..i want set bottom / center

Comment: even with setting line-height:280px; for div and vertical-align:baseline for img?

Comment: can you post generated html (showed in developer tool) on your post?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20043/discussion-between-behnam-esmaili-and-niloo-rg)

Answer (score 1):

To center the image within the DIV:

1. Remove align="center" from the DIV
2. Add the css style "text-align:center;" to the DIV.
3. Remove the "position:absolute; bottom:0;" from the DIV.

That should do it.

Comment: Thanks, i use position for set image bottom of div. i use align="center" don't work.

Comment: Hi, here's a fiddle showing how to center an image in a div. It's really simple. Just follow what's in here: http://jsfiddle.net/wHLFN/